# Loop Cut won't go around object

Tags: edit-mode

I have a cube that has been divided and reshaped. Some faces have been deleted and recreated along the way, but there is a currently a face on all sides and I have all quads.

I can't figure out why it won't let me perform a loop cut here.

[image]

I have already checked and there are no duplicate vertices. There are exactly 12 in this section that is visible when I used the rubberband tool and "Merge by Distance" no longer removes any.

The red line in the picture is where I used "Mark Seam"

with my understanding of the way it works, I would have thought I should be able to make a loop cut here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. I recreated the shape you have, and you SHOULD be able to make a cut there, provided everything is in proper order. When you merge by distance, have you tried increasing the value a bit beyond the default to make sure it catches any verts that are more than 0.0001m apart?

Comment: I had tried that and also did a rubberband select to make sure that there were only 12 vertices in total. It ended up just being me not doing it properly. Still learning...

Comment: I cannot duplicate -when i try I get a loopcut that goes all the way around. Can you provide a blend so I can duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I figured it out. I didn't actually recreate the object properly. I had closed the edge using the 'F' key so the Face wasn't actually subdivided, so one side has 6 vertices and one side has 4.

I deleted the edge and used the knife tool to recreate the line in the middle and it all works properly now.

[image]